# Different ways of implementing atomic *=

Tags: c++, atomic

Studying through a book, it explains how to implement more complex operations like `operator*` for `std::atomic<T>`. Implementation uses `compare_exchange_weak` and I think I understood how this works. Now, I implemented things myself, take a look.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>

/*template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>>
std::atomic<T>& operator*=(std::atomic<T>& t1, T t2) {
    T expected = t1.load();
    while(!t1.compare_exchange_weak(expected, expected * t2))
    {}
    return t1;
}*/

template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>>
std::atomic<T>& operator*=(std::atomic<T>& t1, T t2) {
    T expected = t1.load();
    t1.compare_exchange_weak(expected, expected * t2);
    return t1;
}

int main() {
    std::atomic<int> t1 = 5;
    std::atomic<int> t2;
    t2 = (t1 *= 5).load();

    std::cout << "Atomic t1: " << t1 << "\n";
    std::cout << "Atomic t2: " << t2 << "\n";
}
```

I have two versions of the code, book's version is commented out. I don't get why I should wait on a busy-loop to perform atomic `compare_exchange`. In my version, I've just called it on its own line and looking at the generated assembly in Godbolt, both uses

```
lock cmpxchg dword ptr [rsp + 8], ecx
```

and looks pretty similar to me. So, why should I need a wait-loop like the one in the book to make this thing atomic? Isn't my version also fine and do work atomically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Imagine between your call to `load` and `compare_exchange_weak` the value gets changed by another thread. `expected` has no longer the current value.

`compare_exchange_weak` works as follows:

> Atomically compares the (object representation (until C++20)/ value
>   representation (since C++20)) of *this with that of expected, and if
>   those are bitwise-equal, replaces the former with desired (performs
>   read-modify-write operation). Otherwise, loads the actual value stored
>   in *this into expected (performs load operation).
>   [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange)

Based on the description above `t1` would not be altered and your multiplication would not be stored.
By looping you ensure to either update `t1` and store the result of the multiplication or to update `expected` and to try again in the next iteration of the loop (the loop does only stop once the first case occurred).

---

EDIT:
You can "try" it by simulating the concurrent access. Before exchanging the result another thread comes in and changes the value of the atomic. In the following the `compare_exchange_weak` only affects `expected`.

```
+----------- Thread 1 -----------+---------- Thread 2 ----------+
| ex = t1.load()                 |                              |
|                                | t1.store(42)                 |
| t1.cmp_xchg_w(ex, ex * t2)     |                              |
```

This code simulates the concurrent access and letting individual threads sleep.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>>
std::atomic<T>& operator*=(std::atomic<T>& t1, T t2) {
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    T expected = t1.load();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(400ms);
    t1.compare_exchange_weak(expected, expected * t2);
    return t1;
}

int main() {
    std::atomic<int> t1 = 5;
    std::atomic<int> t2;
    std::thread th1([&](){
        t2 = (t1 *= 5).load();
    });
    std::thread th2([&](){
        using namespace std::chrono_literals;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);
        t1.store(8);
    });

    th1.join();
    th2.join();

    std::cout << "Atomic t1: " << t1 << "\n";
    std::cout << "Atomic t2: " << t2 << "\n";
}
```